# Mapping between Azure REST API and .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

After much searching, cannot find good documentation on the Azure .NET SDK, specifically on how to find which classes implement a given API action. For example, say I've found a REST API request to list all subscriptions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790531.aspx

Now, if I want to use the Azure .Net SDK to make this call, how do I find which library and class has this corresponding method?

(In this case it is Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources.SubscriptionClient, but I only know that through manually exploring the source code and Nuget package)

Comment: The SDK files are *generated* from the REST API's Swagger description and the [AutoRest](https://github.com/azure/autorest) project. SubscriptionClient is such a [generated class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/21db6e5490e66af39a9c6dbf0ad10650d9ca037b/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/ResourceManagement/Generated/SubscriptionClient.cs)

Comment: Thanks - I realize the SDK is generated, but that still leaves the question of how to find the class from the API documentation. How do I know that if I see a URL like "<https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?$skiptoken={skiptoken}&api-version={api-version}>", I should  go looking for a class called "SubscriptionClient"?

Comment: Rougly - yes. You need to find which project was generated for an API. From that point though, all generated classes follow the same conventions. Eg, Subscriptions is a Resource so it appears as a property on the client. The documented operations appear as methods, eg ListAsync, ListLocationsAsync, GetAsync. This means that the REST API documentation really is *the* documentation.

Comment: @NoahStahl.. did you find any mapping list for API and SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Azure documentation is very lacking in a lot of places. With huge amounts of automated documentation (if you're lucky) and exceptionally little 'this is what it means' guidance.

As far as I'm aware, the only way to figure these things out is to dig through the source code and hope you can piece together how the Azure backend works. Over the last couple of years that I've spent working on Azure I've yet to find a better way of working out how Azure works than poking at the source code and trying to make things work.

(to be fair, I've had similar complaints, and heard similar things about AWS)