# Azure REST API to .NET SDK object mapping

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-rest-api

I've searched for examples but couldn't find out exactly how the Azure SDK for .NET works.

Project is a **net5.0** ASP.NET MVC.

There's already a question [Mapping between Azure REST API and .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180959/mapping-between-azure-rest-api-and-net-sdk) but it doesn't answer anything. There are good examples here: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Microsoft.Azure.Subscriptions/SubscriptionClient/-/php-subscriptionclient-class-examples.html but none of them seem to work for me fully (see next lines).

`Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.Subscription` has half of the fields `get` only, without `set`.

Recommended `Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.Models.Subscription` has everything `get` only.
I cannot create objects with these namespaces.

```cs
        [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation" })]
        private async Task<Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.Subscription> GetUserSubscriptions()
        {
            var accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
            Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.Subscription sub = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.Subscription();
            
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.ManagementScopes);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    sub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.Subscription>(apiResponse);
                }
            }
            return sub;
        }
```

The variable apiResponse correctly retrieves the JSON information, but JsonConvert doesn't convert correctly.

Question:

How can I use Azure SDK (or any other) to map the API responses to objects that I can then manipulate.

Comment: COuld you please tell me what you want to do?

Comment: I want to map received JSON response to an object within an SDK so I wouldn't have to write all of the objects myself

Comment: Hi. Regarding the issue, you can directly use Azure SDK  to implement your need. Do not call the API by yourself then convert response to Azure SDk object. Regarding how to use the sdk, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net